# Unable to display custom list view from SP web page into SP webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online

A newbie here in SharePoint would like to ask, with the above title given. I have used a certain script to pull this custom list view's data to be able to display on a webpart. 
However, the webpart was not able to display the custom list view. What might be possible reasons?

I took my script from this website: http://usermanagedsolutions.com/SharePoint-User-Toolkit/Pages/Cross-Site-List-Snapshot.aspx

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What script you use to display custom list view?

What’s the experience you use in SharePoint Online, classic or modern?

Why not use the OOB list view web part in the page?

For the classic experience, you can insert the App web part and select relevant list.

For the modern experience, you can add the List(preview) web part, or use Embed web part.

Comment: It is a JavaScript, to pull data from a SP page that uses custom list view to a blank web page. But however, the supposedly list view to display keeps rendering.
And yeah, I'm using Sharepoint Online.